# "Aw Snap" error when loading large image using FileReader API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, filereader

I am trying to allow a user to upload an image onto a canvas of size 200MB, but when I choose that image, I get the aw snap error from google chrome. I thought there were no limitations on the FileReader API in terms of image size.

If I set the image.src to that large image within the code, it loads in seconds. But for some reason it keeps crashing when the user tries to load it. If anyone can help with this that would be great. Or if there are any suggestions on how to load a large image to a canvas other than this that would also be great.

Thanks

```
function handleImage(e){                
                    //clearAnnotations(); 
                    //annoRedraw();
                    //redraw();

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(event){
                            image.src = event.target.result;
                            redraw();
                    }

                    imageName = e.target.files[0].name;

                    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]); 
                    imageLoadedCheck();
            }
```

and handleImage function is called by this listener

```
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Charlie, just added the code

Comment: These might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217652/html5-file-api-crashes-chrome-when-using-readasdataurl-to-load-a-selected-image, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920039/html5-object-tag-with-base64-data-content-causes-chrome-to-crash, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=240682

Comment: Thanks for your help Charlie. I used the first link you gave me, and I it loads as the background of my entire page, but when I remove that last line "document.body.appendChild(img)" and make it so that it's drawn onto the canvas it doesn't draw

Comment: I got it working, Thanks for the help Charlie.

Comment: You're awesome @Charlie!!!

Comment: What was the solution that worked for you @flash