# Fail to read audio from blob url in mobile Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, audio, blob

I want to use mp3 playing in my mobile web app, so I wrote a test app, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7921481/1904627) solution but blob URL seems to be broken and empty while file is rightly readed.

```
<input type="file" accept=".mp3" onchange="autoplay()">
<script>
    var file, url, audio, source;
function autoplay(){
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    file = document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files[0];
    url = decodeURIComponent(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    audio = document.createElement("audio");
    source = document.createElement("source");
    source.src = url;
    audio.appendChild(source);
    document.body.appendChild(audio);
    audio.play();
}
</script>
```

Blob size is wrong, I've put bigger file
[image: Blob size is wrong]

EDIT:

I used older version with FileReader, maybe this is not good choice but it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `decodeURIComponent` just do `URL.createObjectURL`

```js
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function autoplay(evt) {
  var file = document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files[0];
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  var audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = url;
  audio.play().catch(function(err){
    console.error(err) // could not play audio
  });
  audio.controls = true;
  document.body.appendChild(audio);
}

document.querySelector("input[type=file]").onchange = autoplay
```

```html
<input type="file" accept=".mp3">
```

btw, I get problem playing it directly, it's weird since the `event.isTrusted` is true, that's why i appended the audio to the DOM

Comment: Thanks, I used it without  decodeURIComponent and I've got same problem - file was just empty, then I decided to use FileReader - it works but with bigger files it crash mobile browser